# I am trying to send form array to backend using dataform but I am not getting array object while debugging

Tags: java, angular, typescript

```
    Below is my code : I am trying to send arrayControl to java spring but while debugging no object is coming in data form.       


saveFormFields(){
const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
this.DataForm.userSessionDataForm = JSON.parse(currentUser);
this.arrayControl = this.DataFormGroup.get('itemRows') as FormArray;
this.DataForm.DocumentDataForm=this.arrayControl.value;
this.Service.save(this.DataForm).subscribe(resp => {
this.DataForm = resp as DataForm;
}, error => {
console.log(error);
this.snotifyService.error(error);
})
}
```

This is my java code where I am trying to get ArrayList

```
`@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUpdate/{userToken}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody void saveUpdate(@RequestBody DataForm dataForm,
                @PathVariable("userToken") String userToken, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ProcessFailed, IOException {

            try {
                if (!userTokenUtil.isTokenExpired(userToken)) {

                DataForm saveUpdate = searchService.saveAndUpdate(dataForm);
                    SecurityUtils.sendResponse(response,HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, saveUpdate );
                }else {
                    SecurityUtils.sendError(response, new BadCredentialsException("Invalid password."),
                            HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication failed");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error:  " + e.getMessage());
                SecurityUtils.sendError(response, new ProcessFailed(e.getMessage()),
                        HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, e.getMessage());
            }
        }`
```

Below is my from code:

```
    <mat-step [stepControl]="DataFormGroup.get('Reference')">
                    <form [formGroup]="DataFormGroup" class="doing-form" #Reference="ngForm">

                        <div>
                            <mat-card class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
                                <mat-card-header>
                                    <mat-card-title>7. Review the reference  with short description</mat-card-title>
                                </mat-card-header>
                                <mat-card-content>
                                    <div class="doing-instructions">
                                        <p class="learning-example">Instruction:</p>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Compare the working </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="doing-example">
                                        <mat-expansion-panel>
                                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                                <mat-panel-title>Example</mat-panel-title>
                                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li></li>
                                                <li></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="text-right">
                           <span(click)="allExpandState=false;expandLess(4)">

<mat-icon class="expansion">expand_less</mat-icon>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <h6>Do you have document?</h6>&nbsp;
                                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="Reference" [(ngModel)]="checkTable">
                                        <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="true">Yes</mat-radio-button>&nbsp;
                                        <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="false">No</mat-radio-button>
                                    </mat-radio-group>
                                    <mat-error *ngIf="DataFormGroup.get('Reference').errors?.required && Reference.submitted">Please select atleast one option</mat-error>

                                    <br>&nbsp;
                                    <div style="overflow-x:auto;" *ngIf="checkTable == 'true' ">
                                        <p>List the documents in the below table</p>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="document">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Country Name</th>
                                                    <th>Document </th>
                                                    <th>Reference</th>
                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Title </th>

                                                    <th>Action</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <div formArrayName="itemRows">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr *ngFor="let itemrow of DataFormGroup.controls.itemRows.controls.slice(0,15); let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="countryName" >
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <mat-radio-group formControlName="document">
                                                                <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="xyz">Hello</mat-radio-button>&nbsp;
                                                                <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="abc">Bye</mat-radio-button>

                                                            </mat-radio-group>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="reference" >
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="Name" >
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="title" >
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="Difference">
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="DataFormGroup.controls.itemRows.controls.length > 1" (click)="deleteRow(i)"
                                                                color="basic">
                                                                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                                            </button>
                                                            <button mat-raised-button (click)="addNewRow()" color="primary">
                                                                <mat-icon >add</mat-icon>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </div>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>&nbsp;

                                    <!-- <button mat-raised-button (click)="autoSaveFunctionCall()">Submit</button> -->
                                </mat-card-content>
                            </mat-card>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <button mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious class="back">BACK</button>
                            </div>
                            <button mat-flat-button matStepperNext color="primary" class="next" (click)="saveFormFields()">NEXT</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </mat-step>
```

dataForm should get value of DocumentDataForm as ArrayList but it is showing element:Object[0],size[0].

Actually I want to save the table in database in which i am getting multiple rows from the user on clicking of add button.

Comment: can you post your form code ?

Comment: form code posted@CruelEngine

Comment: you want to get the form Value right ?

Comment: if form value is what you want @ankitmishra , you can just use ``this.DataForm.value`` inside the click handler

Comment: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'DataForm'.--It is showing like this

Comment: Actually i am able to print dataform value As{[0: {countryName: "", documentStatus: "", referenceNumber: ""]} .I want to pass this array in dataForm, while printing at console it is showing but at server side it is showing object[0] while debugging

Comment: @CruelEngine:I want to submit FormArray of FormGroup to server